# Retrieving updated data from View to AngularJS controller

Tags: html, angularjs, angular

I looked up for solutions but I am not getting the right one for my problem and I need help understanding how to link my object-data-updates to my controller.

I have something like this:

```
<body ng-app="SampleApplication">
  <div ng-controller="SampleController">
    <div ng-repeat="catalogItem in catalogItemList">
       <lable>{{catalogItem.name}}</label>
       <input type="text" ng-model="catalogItem.quantity" />

   </div>
</div>
<a href="#proceed">Proceed</a>
```

In my Controler I have something like the following:

```
 var myApp = angular.module('SampleApplication',[]);

  myApp.controller('SampleController', ['$scope', function($scope, $http) {
       $http.get('hello.com/').then(function(response){

       $scope.catalogItemList = response.data.catalogItemList;// this works       nicely. The data is displayed on my view nicely
 })
          }]);
```

after editing  catalogItem.quantity, I press "Proceed" button, which takes me to another controler, but at this point, in that controller, I see that the values of the quantity have not changed.

```
       myApp.controller('SampleController', ['$scope', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.post('hello.com/addItems', $scope.catalogItemList);
 }
```

At the server side, I noticed that the received `catalogItemList` contains original values. The values of catalogItem.quantity remains the same.

Can you please help me properly harvest data from my html into the controller?

Comment: What is the code that executes when you click on `Proceed` button?

Comment: The last part above 'SampleController' with `http.post`

Comment: So basically is that the data does get to my controller, but I'm getting the old values